# For loop in for loop Django template

Tags: python, django, templates, python-requests

i want to set up 'send request/cancel request' function in template. 
The problem with displaying, if request exist 'cancel', if not 'send'.
I don't get how to correctly get request and compare 'profile' with 'to_profile'. 
Now i got stuck with 'for' loop in 'for' loop... \

In template it shows 3 buttons( the same quantity requests from this event ) for one profile
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9xwT.jpg)

Could you give me some tips how to fix, avoid, or do in another way please. 
Thank you!

request model

```
class EventInviteRequest(models.Model):
    from_event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='from_event', null=True)
    to_profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='to_profile', null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"From {self.from_event} to {self.to_profile}"
```

view i try to use

```
def get_list_of_all_users(request, event_id):
    """Get list of all users"""
    event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
    profiles = Profile.objects.all()
    requests = EventInviteRequest.objects.filter(from_event=event)

    context = {'profiles': profiles, 'event': event, 'requests': requests}
    return render(request, 'events/invite_all_profiles_to_event.html', context)
```

template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}All profiles{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    
    <h3>All profiles:</h3>

    {% for profile in profiles %}
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px; text-align: center;">
        <a href="{% url 'account:profile' profile.id %}">
            {% if profile.photo %}
                <img src="{{ profile.photo.url }}" width="70" height="100">
            {% else %}
                <img src="{% static 'images/no_img/no_img.png' %}" width="70" height="100">
            {% endif %} 
            <h4>{{ profile.user }}</h4>
        </a>
        {% if request.user == profile.user %}
            <p>You</p>
        {% else %}
            {% if profile in request.user.profile.friends.all %}
                <p>Friends</p>
            {% else %}
                {% if profile == request.user.profile %}
                {% else %}
                    <a href="{% url 'account:send' profile.id %}">Add to friends</a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            <br>
        {% endif %}
        {% if request.user.profile == profile %}
        {% else %}
        <br>
            The problem here
            {% for req in requests %}
                {% if req.to_profile == profile %}
                    <a href="{% url 'events:cancel_event_invite' event.id profile.id %}">Cancel</a>
                    <br>
                {% else %}
                    <a href="{% url 'events:invite_user_to_event' event.id profile.id %}">Invite to event</a>
                    <br>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% empty %}
        <p>No profiles yet</p>
    {% endfor %}
    
{% endblock %}
```

**Update**
I found the solution, i am not sure how good it is, but atm for me it works.

```
{% for req in profile.to_profile.all %}
        {% if profile == req.to_profile %}
            <a href="{% url 'events:cancel_event_invite' event.id profile.id %}">Cancel</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% url 'events:invite_profile_redirect' event.id profile.id %}">Invite to event</a>
        {% endif %}
{% empty %}
    <a href="{% url 'events:invite_profile_redirect' event.id profile.id %}">Invite to event</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like this.
models.py

```
class EventInviteRequest(models.Model):
    from_event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='from_event', blank=True,null=True)
    to_profile = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='to_profile', blank=True,null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"From {self.from_event}"
```

1. run `python manage.py makemigrations`
2. run `python manage.py migrate`

views.py

```
def get_list_of_all_users(request, event_id):
    """Get list of all users"""
    event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
    profiles = Profile.objects.all()
    requests = EventInviteRequest.objects.filter(from_event=event)

    context = {'profiles': profiles, 'event': event, 'requests': requests}
    return render(request, 'events/invite_all_profiles_to_event.html', context)
```

in your template where you have problems

```
{% for req in requests %}
                {% if profile in req.to_profile.all %}
                    <a href="{% url 'events:cancel_event_invite' event.id profile.id %}">Cancel</a>
                    <br>
                {% else %}
                    <a href="{% url 'events:invite_user_to_event' event.id profile.id %}">Invite to event</a>
                    <br>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have done like you wrote, but now in template it can not detect any existing requests, and return only "invite to event" buttons 3 for each profile.

Comment: @sergey try to delete all your row in the db.if you have 3 invite button for every profile this means that you have duplicated data.go to your admin page add data and test it.